# cookies and sessions are not being saved

Tags: php, session, cookies, pdo

my site is working (sort off). When i check if there sessions are there, they echo out a message which works BUT when i check session storage in chrome, the sessions are not coming up, which is strange. I have also tried to set a cookie but that is not coming up either. So what am i doing wrong. So the sessions are working but not getting stored, and the cookies are not getting stored either

this is part of login class

```
public function __construct(DB $pdo)
{
    $this->pdo = $pdo->pdo;

    if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
        $_SESSION = array();
        session_destroy();
    }

}

public function checklogin()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_sess']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] === true){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function loginwithdata($email, $password)
{
    $query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ?');

    $query->bindValue(1, $email);

    try{

    $query->execute();

    $data = $query->fetch();

    $salt = $data['salt'];
    $user_key = $data['user_key'];
    $hashed_pass = sha1(md5($salt.$password));

    if($this->verify($hashed_pass, $email) === true){

        $_SESSION['user_sess'] = $user_key;
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
        setcookie('key', '12345678910', 1209600, '/');
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

here is the ajax_login.php

```
require '../core/init.php';

if(isset($_POST))
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(!empty($email) && (!empty($password))){

        $try = $login->loginwithdata($email, $password);

        if($try){
            //login successful
            echo 'success';
        } else {
            echo 'login failed';
        }
    }
} 

and on my index page i have

require_once 'core/init.php';

if($login->checklogin() === true){
    echo "you are logged in";
} else if ($login->checklogin() === false) {
    echo "you are not logged in";
}
```

and my init file

```
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

require_once 'classes/DB.php';
require_once 'classes/Upload.php';
require_once 'classes/Login.php';
require_once 'classes/Register.php';
require_once 'classes/Site.php';
require_once 'classes/Admin.php';

require_once 'sinitize.php';

$pdo        = new DB;
$upload     = new Upload($pdo);
$login      = new Login($pdo);
$register   = new Register($pdo);
```

Comment: Do you have `session_start();` in every script using, starting or destroying the session?

Comment: yeah iv i include the init.php file on everypage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good so far.

But wait.. dude.. Sessions generally get stored in a COOKIE (as ID). SESSION STORAGE and WEB STORAGE in chrome is something completely different and is sorta part of HTML5 rather than PHP Sessions.

You say you get the proper echoes so there is really nothing wrong with your session.
If you open the developers console and in networking tab you see the cookie sent, it's everything perfect.

If you are having problems with the session cookie itself,
please provide and check the session configuration variables from php.ini:

From console:

```
php -i | grep session
```

or use `phpinfo();` in a web served script.

`session.use_cookies` should be On

See: http://www.php.net/manual/de/ini.list.php

Comment: thanks :D i thought the session storage had something to do with it lol its just the cookie which is not setting now

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers, **if path is set**, wants the domain too:

```
setcookie ( $name, $value, $expire, $path,  $domain);
```

About $expire
It's the "absolute" time in seconds since Epoc when the cookie expire, so expire within an hour should be:

```
$expire = time()+3600;
```

see also:
http://www.php.net/setcookie

Comment: at the moment im working on a sub folder so would it be setcookie('key', '2929292', '1209600', '/', 'www.mydomain.com/test');

Comment: A more correct form: setcookie('key', '2929292', '1209600', '/test', 'www.mydomain.com')

Comment: PHP sets the cookie upon `session_start()`, no need to set the cookie manually

Comment: iv added session_start() on every page, as i include init.php

Comment: If you set expire to "1209600" it HAS expired since **14 Jan 1970**

Comment: Heheheh, it's the way to **remove** a "time attributed" cookie!